Splitting of the d$_{xy}$ orbital in square planar transition metal complexes
In square planar complexes, the d$_{x^2-y^2}$ occupies the highest energy level due to it interacting greatest with the ligands. The d$_{z^2}$ orbital is also raised slightly higher in energy than the d$_{xz}$ and d$_{yz}$ orbitals as the toroid can interact slightly with the ligands
Why is the d$_{xy}$ orbital raised higher in energy than the d$_{xz}$ and d$_{yz}$. Whilst it may lie in the plane of the 4 ligands, it sits in between the x and y axis unlike the d$_{x^2-y^2}$ orbital. Would this not result in a net 0 interaction with ligands, as they overlap equally with both the positive and negative parts of the orbital

if you're looking at it from orbital overlap perspective, you have to include pi interactions to get that splitting. In crystal field theory, the concept of net zero overlap doesn't exist so it's simply a matter of interacting with more ligands in the xy plane than the other two planes.
